# C program to simule a simple calculator

Tags: c, input, logic, scanf

I am learning C program. I wrote a program to create a calculator using switch statement. When I tried to run this code the program stops in the middle of it when running, I realized what the problem was, I show you my three attemps, the first one is the correct one but I woud like to know why the others two didn't work.

```
  // Calculator
    #include <stdio.h> 
   int main ()
   {
        int num1, num2;
        char key;
        printf("CALCULATOR \n");
        printf("choose +, -, *, / or %% \n");
        scanf("%c", &key);
        printf("Enter two integers\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

        switch(key)
              {
                   case '+': printf("%d", num1 + num2);
                           break;
                   case '-': printf("%d", num1 - num2);
                           break;
                   case '*': printf("%d", num1 * num2);
                           break;
                   case '/': printf("%d", num1/num2);
                           break;
                   case '%': printf("%d", num1%num2);
                            break;
                   default: printf("syntax error");                 
              }
                  return 0;
     } // the correc one
```

but these two are wrong, I want to know why if the logic is the same.

```
            // Calculator
            #include <stdio.h>
            int main ()
            {
                int num1, num2;
                char key;
                printf("CALCULATOR \n");
                printf("Enter two integers\n");
                scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
                printf("choose +, -, *, / or %% \n");
                scanf("%c", &key);
                
                switch(key)
                {
                    case '+': printf("%d", num1 + num2);
                        break;
                    case '-': printf("%d", num1 - num2);
                        break;
                    case '*': printf("%d", num1 * num2);
                        break;
                    case '/': printf("%d", num1/num2);
                        break;
                    case '%': printf("%d", num1%num2);
                        break;
                    default: printf("syntax error");                    
                }
                return 0;
            } //wrong
```

the last one

```
            // Calculator
            #include <stdio.h>
            int main ()
            {
                int num1, num2;
                char key;
                printf("CALCULATOR \n");
                printf("Enter a integer\n");
                scanf("%d", &num1);
                printf("choose +, -, *, / or %% \n");
                scanf("%c", &key);
                printf("Enter a integer\n");
                scanf("%d", &num2);
                
                switch(key)
                {
                    case '+': printf("%d", num1 + num2);
                        break;
                    case '-': printf("%d", num1 - num2);
                        break;
                    case '*': printf("%d", num1 * num2);
                        break;
                    case '/': printf("%d", num1/num2);
                        break;
                    case '%': printf("%d", num1%num2);
                        break;
                    default: printf("syntax error");                    
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

I'd appreciate an answer.

Comment: Time to strap this into a debugger and find out what's going on.

Comment: Indeed.  Not even a debugger is required.  Just basic investigative abilities.  You could have printed out all values and figured it out straight away.  Then searched for appropriate questions on that topic (which are easy to find), if you were unsure why this happened.